# Explanation of step in solving homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, homogeneous-equation

I've recently started learning homogenous differential equations after having studied equations with seperable variables.  Could you explain how changing variables $u=\dfrac{y}{x} \Longrightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dx}=x\dfrac{du}{dx}+u$.

[image]

Comment: If we let $u = \dfrac{y}{x}$, we have $$y = u x \implies y' = u + u' x$$ Now substitute $y$ and $y'$ into the original equation and simplify. Clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Moo said you just substitute in the original equation
$$u=\frac yx \implies y=ux \implies y'=u'x+u $$
$$y'=e^{y/x}+\frac yx$$
$$u'x+u=e^u+u$$
$$u'x=e^u$$
$$x\frac {du}{dx}=e^u \implies e^{-u}du=\frac {dx}x$$
Integrate
$$\int \frac {du}{e^u}=\int \frac {dx}x$$
$$-e^{-u}=\ln(x)+K$$
$$e^{-y/x}=-\ln(x)+C$$

Comment: Looks good to me +1! :-)

Comment: Thank you Moo...

Comment: @Isham Thanks! and where did we use the fact that this differential equation satisfies the properties of homogeneous equations?

Comment: Well when you choose the substitution $u=y/x$ or $y=ux$ when it's not the equation cant be solved that easily here it works fine with this kind of substitution @johnfowles Try that substitution on an equation that is not homogeneous and see what happen